# Built in .Net algorithm to round value to the nearest 10 interval

Tags: c#, math, rounding

How to, in C# round any value to 10 interval? For example, if I have 11, I want it to return 10, if I have 136, then I want it to return 140.

I can easily do it by hand

```
return ((int)(number / 10)) * 10;
```

But I am looking for an builtin algorithm to do this job, something like Math.Round(). The reason why I won't want to do by hand is that I don't want to write same or similar piece of code all over my projects, even for something as simple as the above.

Comment: If it works, why do you need something else? Just wrap it up in an extension method or common library and run with it

Comment: ((number + 5)/10) * 10 -- good reason to find a built-in. :-)

Comment: I noticed there's confusion with this question, and you probably should edit the title or posting to make it more clear.  In particular, do you want to always round up, or round to the nearest 10?

Comment: Raymond, based on the actual content of the question, rather than the title, it's obvious that it's about rounding to the nearest 10. But I've noticed that ambiguity, too, and agree the title should be altered to fit.

Comment: @Adam: What is wrong with wrapping a simple and straightforward line of code in a method?  Doesn't look tricky or confusing to me.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

There is no built-in function in the class library that will do this. The closest is [System.Math.Round()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) which is only for rounding numbers of types Decimal and Double to the nearest integer value. However, you can wrap your statement up in a extension method, if you are working with .NET 3.5, which will allow you to use the function much more cleanly.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int RoundOff (this int i)
    {
        return ((int)Math.Round(i / 10.0)) * 10;
    }
}

int roundedNumber = 236.RoundOff(); // returns 240
int roundedNumber2 = 11.RoundOff(); // returns 10
```

If you are programming against an older version of the .NET framework, just remove the "this" from the RoundOff function, and call the function like so:

```
int roundedNumber = ExtensionMethods.RoundOff(236); // returns 240
int roundedNumber2 = ExtensionMethods.RoundOff(11); // returns 10
```

Comment: There's a bunch of problems with this code, namely it doesn't compile (missing return type) and it doesn't round to the nearest. In your example, it returns 230 and 10.

Comment: It still won't return 240, because you're rounding down.

Comment: Actually run it. Here's the source (including a test class), and even a build of the source. It works, and correctly. http://labs.coldacid.net/code/number-rounding-extension-method

Comment: Ah, but you're original answer didn't use Math.Round() at all.

Comment: Also, you changed 10 into 10.0, which is useful to know, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: The question asks to "round up" but this answer rounds off. If you input 11 you should get back 20, not 10. This is why you need `Math.Ceiling()`.

Comment: Dan Diplo: The very next sentence, where OP explains what he wants, describes rounding off. Read the whole question, not just the first sentence of it.

Comment: A very small error but thought I'd point out as it is not that obvious. If you loop from (0 to 100) and print all the values the very first time (i = 5) it rounds to zero. But for all the other values it rounds as expected (i = 15, rounds to 20) etc. I'm assuming this has to do with multiplying and dividing with a value of zero.

Answer (score 28):

Use Math.Ceiling to always round up.

```
int number = 236;
number = (int)(Math.Ceiling(number / 10.0d) * 10);
```

Modulus(%) gets the remainder, so you get:

```
// number = 236 + 10 - 6
```

Put that into an extension method

```
public static int roundupbyten(this int i){
    // return i + (10 - i % 10); <-- logic error. Oops!
    return (int)(Math.Ceiling(i / 10.0d)*10); // fixed
}

// call like so:
int number = 236.roundupbyten();
```

above edited: I should've gone with my first instinct to use Math.Ceiling

I [blogged about this when calculating UPC check digits](http://atomiton.blogspot.com/2007/12/calculating-checkdigit-using.html).

Comment: Try it with 240. What do you get then? Or for that matter, 11.

Answer (score 25):

This might be a little too late but I guess this might be of good help someday...

I have tried this:

```
public int RoundOff(int number, int interval){
    int remainder = number % interval;
    number += (remainder < interval / 2) ? -remainder : (interval - remainder);
    return number;
}
```

To use:

```
int number = 11;
int roundednumber = RoundOff(number, 10);
```

This way, you have the option whether if the half of the interval will be rounded up or rounded down. =)

Comment: simple, effective, adaptable. well done.

Comment: this gives wrong answer. using interval of 15, 7 should be 0 but gives 15. 22 gives 30, but should be 15. i think "remainder < interval" should be "remainder <= interval". seems to work correctly on my testing. other than that, great answer - very flexible. +1

Answer (score 5):

Rounding a float to an integer is similar to (int)(x+0.5), as opposed to simply casting x - if you want a multiple of 10, you can easily adapt that.

If you just want to do integer math and are rounding it to ten, try (x+10/2)/10*10.

**Edit:** I noticed that this response doesn't meet the original's author's request, and is also a biased form of rounding that I prefer not to do.  However, another accepted response already stated Math.round(), a much better solution.

Comment: I have to say that, even though this is the trick I used in past a lot, Math.Round looks a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but here is a way to do what has been asked plus I extended it to be able to round any number to the number of sig figs you want.

```
    private double Rounding(double d, int digits)
    {
        int neg = 1;
        if (d < 0)
        {
            d = d * (-1);
            neg = -1;
        }

        int n = 0;
        if (d > 1)
        {
            while (d > 1)
            {
                d = d / 10;
                n++;
            }
            d = Math.Round(d * Math.Pow(10, digits));
            d = d * Math.Pow(10, n - digits);
        }
        else
        {
            while (d < 0.1)
            {
                d = d * 10;
                n++;
            }
            d = Math.Round(d * Math.Pow(10, digits));
            d = d / Math.Pow(10, n + digits);
        }

        return d*neg;
    }


   private void testing()
   {
       double a = Rounding(1230435.34553,3);
       double b = Rounding(0.004567023523,4);
       double c = Rounding(-89032.5325,2);
       double d = Rounding(-0.123409,4);
       double e = Rounding(0.503522,1);
       Console.Write(a.ToString() + "\n" + b.ToString() + "\n" + 
           c.ToString() + "\n" + d.ToString() + "\n" + e.ToString() + "\n");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to not bring in the `Math` library nor go to floating point so my suggestion is just do integer arithmetic like below where I round up to the next 1K. Wrap it in a method or lambda snippet or something if you don't want to repeat.

```
int MyRoundedUp1024Int = ((lSomeInteger + 1023) / 1024) * 1024;
```

I have not run performance tests on this vs. other the ways but I'd bet it is the fastest way to do this save maybe a shifting and rotating of bits version of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I round to the nearest multiple of any arbitrary factor without converting from integral types to floating-point values. This works for any int from `int.MinValue + 1` to `int.MaxValue`

I used the [Round half away from zero equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero), `Round(x) = sgn(x)*Floor(Abs(x) + 0.5)`, the fact that `Floor(z) = z - (z%1)`, and my desired output equation `F(value, factor) = Round(value/factor)*factor` to derive the an equation that doesn't require precise decimal division.

```
public static int RoundToNearestMultipleOfFactor(this int value, int factor)
{
    if (factor == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(factor), factor, "Cannot be zero");
    }

    var halfAbsFactor = Math.Abs(factor) >> 1;
    return value + Math.Sign(value) * (halfAbsFactor - (Math.Abs(value) % factor + halfAbsFactor % factor) % factor);
}
```

Here's the entire extension method class with methods for both `int` and `long` as well as methods to round only toward or away from zero.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension methods for rounding integral numeric types
/// </summary>
public static class IntegralRoundingExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Rounds to the nearest multiple of a <paramref name="factor"/> using <see cref="MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero"/> for midpoints.
    /// <para>
    /// Performs the operation Round(value / factor) * factor without converting to a floating type.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to round.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor to round to a multiple of. Must not be zero. Sign does not matter.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Uses math derived from the <see href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero">Round half away from zero equation</see>: y = sgn(x)*Floor(Abs(x) + 0.5) and floor equation: Floor(z) = z - (z % 1)
    /// </remarks>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">If <paramref name="factor"/> is zero</exception>
    /// <seealso cref="MidpointRounding"/>
    public static long RoundToNearestMultipleOfFactor(this long value, long factor)
    {
        if (factor == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(factor), factor, "Cannot be zero");
        }

        var halfAbsFactor = Math.Abs(factor) >> 1;
        // return value + Math.Sign(value) * (halfAbsFactor - ((Math.Abs(value) + halfAbsFactor) % factor));
        //fix overflow
        return value + Math.Sign(value) * (halfAbsFactor - (Math.Abs(value) % factor + halfAbsFactor % factor) % factor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Round to the nearest multiple of <paramref name="factor"/> with magnitude less than or equal to <paramref name="value"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to round.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor to round to a multiple of. Must not be zero. Sign does not matter.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">If <paramref name="factor"/> is zero</exception>
    public static long RoundToMultipleOfFactorTowardZero(this long value, long factor)
    {
        if (factor == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(factor), factor, "Cannot be zero");
        }

        var remainder = value % factor; // negative iff value is negative

        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            return value;
        }

        return value - remainder;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Round to the nearest multiple of <paramref name="factor"/> with magnitude greater than or equal to <paramref name="value"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to round.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor to round to a multiple of. Must not be zero. Sign does not matter.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">If <paramref name="factor"/> is zero</exception>
    public static long RoundToMultipleOfFactorAwayFromZero(this long value, long factor)
    {
        if (factor == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(factor), factor, "Cannot be zero");
        }

        var remainder = value % factor; // negative iff value is negative

        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            return value;
        }

        return value - remainder + Math.Sign(value) * Math.Abs(factor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rounds to the nearest multiple of a <paramref name="factor"/> using <see cref="MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero"/> for midpoints.
    /// <para>
    /// Performs the operation Round(value / factor) * factor without converting to a floating type.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to round.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor to round to a multiple of. Must not be zero. Sign does not matter.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Uses math derived from the <see href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero">Round half away from zero equation</see>: y = sgn(x)*Floor(Abs(x) + 0.5) and floor equation: Floor(z) = z - (z % 1)
    /// </remarks>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">If <paramref name="factor"/> is zero</exception>
    /// <seealso cref="MidpointRounding"/>
    public static int RoundToNearestMultipleOfFactor(this int value, int factor)
    {
        if (factor == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(factor), factor, "Cannot be zero");
        }

        var halfAbsFactor = Math.Abs(factor) >> 1;
        // return value + Math.Sign(value) * (halfAbsFactor - ((Math.Abs(value) + halfAbsFactor) % factor));
        //fix overflow
        return value + Math.Sign(value) * (halfAbsFactor - (Math.Abs(value) % factor + halfAbsFactor % factor) % factor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Round to the nearest multiple of <paramref name="factor"/> with magnitude less than or equal to <paramref name="value"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to round.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor to round to a multiple of. Must not be zero. Sign does not matter.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">If <paramref name="factor"/> is zero</exception>
    public static int RoundToMultipleOfFactorTowardZero(this int value, int factor)
    {
        if (factor == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(factor), factor, "Cannot be zero");
        }

        var remainder = value % factor; // negative iff value is negative

        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            return value;
        }

        return value - remainder;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Round to the nearest multiple of <paramref name="factor"/> with magnitude greater than or equal to <paramref name="value"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to round.</param>
    /// <param name="factor">The factor to round to a multiple of. Must not be zero. Sign does not matter.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">If <paramref name="factor"/> is zero</exception>
    public static int RoundToMultipleOfFactorAwayFromZero(this int value, int factor)
    {
        if (factor == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(factor), factor, "Cannot be zero");
        }

        var remainder = value % factor; // negative iff value is negative

        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            return value;
        }

        return value - remainder + Math.Sign(value) * Math.Abs(factor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a native built-in c# library that rounds integers to the nearest tens place.

If you're using c# 8 or later you can create small switch expression utility methods that can do a lot of cool helpful things. If you're using an older version, `if/else` and `switch case` blocks can be used instead:

```cs
public static int RoundIntToTens(int anInt)
   => (anInt, (anInt < 0 ? 0 - anInt : anInt) % 10) switch
   {
       // If int needs to be "round down" and is negative or positive
       (>= 0, < 5) or (< 0, < 5) => anInt - anInt % 10,
       // If int needs to be "round up" and is NOT negative (but might be 0)
       (>= 0, >= 5) => anInt + (10 - anInt % 10),
       // If int needs to be "round up" and is negative
       (< 0, >= 5) => anInt - (10 + anInt % 10)
    };
```

You would have to import it where ever you use it but that'd be the case with any library unless there's a way to add classes to a global name space.