# How can i make a Method that rounds to the next 5er digit?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Built in .Net algorithm to round value up to the nearest 10 interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274439/built-in-net-algorithm-to-round-value-up-to-the-nearest-10-interval)

HI,
i need a Method that returns next number of the 5er row.
example:
3 -> 5
7 -> 10
8 -> 10
16 ->20

how can i do that?
thx

Comment: I voted to close "exact duplicate". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274439/built-in-net-algorithm-to-round-value-up-to-the-nearest-10-interval

Comment: Not an exact duplicate -- he wants to always round up, not to the nearest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive values:

```
int rounded  = 5 * Math.Ceiling( (double)original / 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   int rounded = original + (5 - original%5);
```

Comment: That's 4/5 good, but for 0 you get 5, 5->10, 10->15, etc. 10%5 is zero, last time I've checked.

Comment: Kobi, you're right. I should have written this as:
rounded = n%5==0?n:n + (5 - n%5)

Comment: FYI, neither of your versions works correctly for negative numbers.