# rounded to the nearest 10's place in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rounding

I want to The numbers are being rounded to the nearest `10`'s place. 
 For example, a number like `17.3` is being rounded to `20.0`.  and want to be allow three significant digits.  Meaning for round to the nearest tenth of a percent as the last step of the process.

**Sample** :

```
    the number is 17.3 ,i want round to 20 ,

    and this number is 13.3 , i want round to 10 ?
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 7):

Chris Charabaruk gives you your desired answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274439/built-in-net-algorithm-to-round-value-to-the-nearest-10-interval)

To get to the core, here is his solution as an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int RoundOff (this int i)
    {
        return ((int)Math.Round(i / 10.0)) * 10;
    }
}

int roundedNumber = 236.RoundOff(); // returns 240
int roundedNumber2 = 11.RoundOff(); // returns 10
```

//edit:
This method only works for int values. You'd have to edit this method to your liking. 
f.e.: 
public static class ExtensionMethods

```
{
    public static double RoundOff (this double i)
    {
       return (Math.Round(i / 10.0)) * 10;
    }
}
```

/edit2: As corak stated you should/could use

```
Math.Round(value / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10
```

Comment: Is the cast to `double` really necessary? And to avoid bankers rounding shenanigans, I'd use `Math.Round(value / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10`

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are correct also, but here's how you'd do it without `Math.Round`:

```
((int)((17.3 + 5) / 10)) * 10 // = 20
((int)((13.3 + 5) / 10)) * 10 // = 10
((int)((15.0 + 5) / 10)) * 10 // = 20
```

Comment: What specific reason do you have for doing it without `Round`? Are you assuming you're doing it more efficiently than the math library is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
double d1 = 17.3;
int rounded1 = ((int)Math.Round(d/10.0)) * 10; // Output is 20

double d2 = 13.3;
int rounded2 = ((int)Math.Round(d/10.0)) * 10; // Output is 10
```

Comment: It will give output `20` if value is 15. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

```
double Num = 16.6;
int intRoundNum = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Num / 10)) * 10);
Console.WriteLine(intRoundNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid casting or pulling in the math library you could also use the modulus operator and do something like the following:

```
int result = number - (number % 10);
if (number % 10 >= 5)
{
    result += 10;
}
```

For your given numbers:

| number | processing | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13.3 | 13.3 - (3.3) | 10 |
| 17.3 | 17.3 - (7.3) + 10 | 20 |