# Round to nearest 5 up C#

Tags: c#, rounding

After following the below mentioned links:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349844/rounded-to-the-nearest-10s-place-in-c-sharp#)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844674/how-to-round-to-the-nearest-whole-number-in-c-sharp)
[Link3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8)
And the list goes on. I don't think I fully grasp the idea of Math.Round.

Lets say I have the following **values [73.59, 46.28]** now I want to road both up to the next 5.

After using `Math.Round(Value / 5) * 5` the end results are as follow is:

> 73.59 => 70
>
> 46.28 => 45

This is working for how the Math.Round was intended to be used. However, I am working with currency and would like it to be the next 5 up. So the desired result would want to be the following:

> 73.59 => 75
>
> 46.28 => 50

I also tried playing around with `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` but I still do not get the desired result. Can somebody please explain or provide guidance to how I could accomplish this task?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @xdtTransform that's not relevant - this question is about rounding to *5*, not the nearest integer, no matter what the rounding strategy. Multiplying by 5 is no accident - it probably came from a relevant duplicate [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531695/round-to-nearest-five)

Comment: So instead of `Math.Round(Value / 5) * 5` you want `Math.Ceiling(Value / 5) * 5`

Comment: When mod of 5 is greater than 0, then add 5 and subtract mod of 5?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846493/how-to-always-round-up-to-the-next-integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To always round up, you should use `Math.Ceiling` instead of `Math.Round`:

```
static int RoundUpToMultipleOf5(decimal value) => (int)Math.Ceiling(value / 5) * 5
```