# How to round up the value end with Zero in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i need to round up the value end with Zero `(end value to be 0, like 450, 55000, 4560).` i want to round up the value with ending zero eg if i got value like `102498` means round up value like `102500` and if i got value like 47504 means round up value like 47500 this i have to do in mvc eg values `999 =>1000` `994=>990` `995=>990` i have to do this roundup in table view page.

Comment: Are you trying to round in C# or Javascript/JQuery?  You have both tagged.

Comment: @NathanChampion @{double totamt = item.PerHourRate * item.TotalHours;} @Math.Round(totamt)  this only  i tried but i donno how to round up with ending zero

Comment: Something like this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274439/built-in-net-algorithm-to-round-value-to-the-nearest-10-interval though typically I believe the last digit of >=5 round up in most algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest starting with:

```
Decimal value = 102498;

var rounded = Math.Round(value / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10;

Console.WriteLine(rounded);
```

The steps are:

- Divide by 10
- Round (.5 up, below .5 down - `AwayFromZero`)
- Multiply by 10 (*this ensures the last digit is always 0*)