# How to round up a number to the tens unit in c#?

Tags: c#, numbers, rounding

how to round up number upper or lower in the simplest way?
for example

36 >>> 40

33 >>> 30

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274439/built-in-net-algorithm-to-round-value-to-the-nearest-10-interval

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [System.Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round). You can specify whether you want to round up/down as well as the interval you want to round to.

Comment: And how would one call `System.Math.Round` to round the integral value `36` to `40`?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge & experience. But your answer has a low quality. Sometimes a comment or a flag/close may be more relevant. To help you improve your answers, please read the [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [How do I write a good answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) & [Answering technical questions helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully).

Comment: Round is for decimal part, as I know and as I quickly checked in the documentation, isn't it ?